# Why can my class references only go up to a first shallow level when using 'this'?

Tags: typescript

I have a class and I'm in a situation where I'm trying to initialize a property with reference's to itself to create an observable. I'm not allowed to do this though as I can only get a shallow reference of the property and can't go deeper.

e.g.

```
class MyClass {
  public objectLiteral = {
    itemOne: {
      subject: new Subject<any>(),
      observable: this.objectLiteral.itemOne.subject.asObservable(), // Does not work (which is what I'm hoping to achieve)
    },
    itemTwo: {
      workingReference: this.objectLiteral // This works though.. : /
    }
  };
}
```

Main Questions:
1. Why can't I go deeper than `this.objectLiteral` inside the objectLiteral ?
2. If possible: How can I initialize the class to create an observable like this?

Things to note:
I have been able to successfully add this in a loop at the constructor, but am really curious about point 1. Why can't I have a deeper reference?

Comment: The `itemOne` attribute does not have a `sibject` attribute, it has one called `subject`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I've updated it. I've tested it though with the right spelling. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that at the point when the object to be assigned to `objectLiteral` is being constructed, `this.objectLiteral` itself is not set to anything. Take the fact you are initialising a class property out of the equation and consider just using ordinary variables:

```
  let objectLiteral = {
    itemOne: {
      subject: new Subject<any>(),
      observable: objectLiteral.itemOne.subject.asObservable(), // Still won't work! `objectLiteral` not yet set
    }
  };
```

You cannot reference the value assigned to `objectLiteral` until after you have assigned it.

The second part may look as though it works, but I think you'll find it is using the value `undefined`:

```
  workingReference: this.objectLiteral // undefined! /
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Just want to double check if I understand this. So because under the hood, at the point when the class property is being initialized with this value, it technically has not yet have a set reference to be used/referred to. So I can only get the reference this.objectLiteral at a later time in my code. (e.g. setTimeout or I guess the constructor (since it worked there)

Comment: Yes, you got it. Any assignment will fully evaluate the right hand side before it actually does the assignment, so if you reference the left hand side in the expression you get the old value which in this case is `undefined`. A simpler example of this is `x = x + 1` where the `x` on the right hand side refers to the old value of `x`.

Comment: Thanks for this man. Really helped with this explanation. : )